# How can I automatically create/control VMs using vsphere?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, automation

Is it possible to automatically create virtual machines using vSphere / ESXi? How would I go about doing that?

I have a script to automatically create + install windows on a VM using VirtualBox. It makes the VM, mounts the CD (which is an unattended XP install resulting in machine shutdown), then unmounts the CD when it notices the machine is off. Can I do something similar w/ vmware's stuff?

both VirtualBox and XenCenter have command line utilities which do things like let you turn machines on/off. Is there an equivalent cmd line utility for vsphere / ESXi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. I thought you are interested in the official [documentation](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vcli/).

**Edit:**
Ok, I could have copied the complete step-by-step guide from [here](http://searchsystemschannel.techtarget.com/feature/Creation-of-virtual-machines-utilizing-command-line-tools). But that would also be too much for an answer.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The documentation is a 150 pages PDF with hundreds of options and parameters depending on the task and the context. Unspecified questions lead to unspecified answers.

Comment: aye no need for him to do my work for me. i was really looking to see where i could get the command line tool

Answer (score 1):

The Orchestration part of vCenter is particularly good at this, it can tie into your networking and storage too.